# How can I disable diff in line separators in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, diff

I'm using Intellij IDEA 14 on Windows and Git as VCS on Unix server.
The line separator in Windows is CLRF (`\r\n`) and LF (`\n`) in Unix.
In Git, I'm using config `--global core.autocrlf input`. This will translate all CRLF's to LF's upon commit.

When I'm using "Reformat code" option on well-formatted file, IDEA marks files as changed and shows diff in line separators only.

[image: Right mouse button on changed file -> Git -> Compare with Latest Repository Version]

How can I disable that in IDEA?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503036/git-and-intellij-lines-separator-issue

Answer (score 35):

In the bottom right of your window, change `[CRLF]` to `[LF]`

Comment: but it shows diff in external tool (ex, Git Extensions) as empty changed file and I can't commit this file.

Comment: Hmm I use git inside intellij. It's much simpler to use imho.

Comment: Global setting: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-line-separators.html

Answer (score 23):

I'm also developing on windows and Because our servers are powered by Linux and all the code has to base on Linux I have preferred to change all my files to LF instead of CRLF.

from git command line:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

i'm working with intellij idea so it's quite easy:

> 1)    File --> settings --> editor --> code style: (for any new file will
>   be created)
>
> a.    Scheme : default
>
> b.    Line separator: unix and os x (\n)
>
> 2)    mark the root of the project --> file --> line separator --> LF
>   unix and os x (\n) (for exist files)

Remark: you can also use apps like dos2unix.exe or some other scripts.

than I did using my command line: (you can do this also from the idea)

```
git commit -m "bla bla"
git add .
git push origin master
```

since then, I didn't got those warnings

Comment: just setting the config didn't change the working tree, pulling didn't either, so i had to clone the repository, and then the line separators were fixed.

Comment: Why do we have to commit everything afterwards? Since the contents are identical.

Comment: I tried rolling back all the files, so I didn't have to commit and push.

Answer (score 7):

If you came to this thread like me seeking an answer as to why your unit test (JUnit) fails on comparing generated JSON (or any other structure that contains line separators) with one written by hand, you should replace \n by \r\n (for Windows) in your string. The instructions given above don't work for this case.

Comment: Thanks dude, that's exactly why I came for :D

Answer (score 2):

select folder -> File -> File Properties -> Line Separator -> LF

All files will be markd as `changed`.

Make regular commit with line separator changes ounly.
It will fail but `changed` marks will disappear.

New files will inherit folder property.

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij 17.3, you can select in the "Compare by" combobox in the compare window whether you want to compare 'Binary content' or 'Text'. In the second case CRLF and LF are not shown as "different".

Comment: Which compare window do you mean?

Answer (score -2):

Create parser.py in the same dir.
Change the name and run.
Enjoy))

```html
with open('./file_to_fix.py', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()

with open('./file_to_fix.py', 'w') as f:
    # for i in a.split('\r\n'):
    #     f.write(i)
    aa = a.replace('\r\n', '\n')
    f.write(aa)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `System.lineSeparator()` in your strings.
It hepled me as my code had to be checked on a Linux server and my local computer uses Windows, so the line separators for these two are different.