# Git and IntelliJ lines separator issue

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am working in `IntelliJ 15.0.3` and using Git through Git Bash (to commit and push changes). When I `fetch` file from remote git repository
it contains different line separators (mixed mode or how it's called).  I mean that some lines ends with `CRLF` and some lines ends with `LF` (the same file).

When I make change in IDEA - file is automatically saved and all line separators are reduced (changed) to IDEA default line separator (`LF` for me).

And git treats these changes as changes to the file, as a result I commit file with a lot of changes like these:

```
- some line
+ some line
```

Because `some line [CRLF]` was changed to `some line [LF]`.

**How to configure `Git` to ignore this or how to configure `IntelliJ IDEA` to leave file in this mix-mode?** I don't want to commit changes when there are no changes.

Comment: While installing GIT, there is an option to say "checkout as-is, commit as-is", that might help you ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While installing git, we will have option to set the `checkout as-is and commit as-is`.

If that is not set, we can do with the git [config](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace).

Following command helps you in doing so.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

As per documentation:

> Git can handle this by auto-converting CRLF line endings into LF when you add a file to the index, and vice versa when it checks out code onto your filesystem. You can turn on this functionality with the core.autocrlf setting. If you’re on a Windows machine, set it to true — this converts LF endings into CRLF when you check out code

Comment: More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy

Comment: I have added git config --global core.autocrlf true but I still have the issue in intellij whenever I commit files. The intellij editor shows "contents have differences only in line seperators" after commiting.

Comment: Yes it is because you set this after fetching. I think the best you can do is copy you changes to somewhere else, discard the changes with `git checkout -- <some file>` or `git checkout -- *.*`(discard all changes) and fetch again.

Answer (score 3):

IDEA delegates changes resolution to git.

So you would have to either [force desired line breaks in IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926888/how-can-i-disable-diff-in-line-separators-in-intellij-idea) or [to force desired line breaks in git](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/handling-lf-and-crlf-line-endings.html).

In my case `autocrlf true` was already present on my PC but the working copy was initially copied from collegue's share where it had been checked out with another setting.

A clean checkout would resolve the problem but I had some files already changed and wanted to preserve them.
This can be worked around by resetting git index for the [whole project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy) or just desired [subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404535/how-to-git-reset-hard-a-subdirectory).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below conifguration to your .gitconfig (for unix based OS only)

```
[core]
    autocrlf = input
    eol = lf
```

You can also make such changes within terminal:

```
 git config --global core.eol lf
 git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Answer (score 1):

At the opposite, if you have an issue with files getting back (while changing branch for example) to CRLF even after changing IntelliJ settings to "Line Separator : LF".
Then set "git config --global core.autocrlf false".

I had this issue constantly while working on windows but with a repo that is configured for a Linux machine.