# Intellij ignore changes only linefeed in git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We all know Intellijs diff which says 

**Image 1** 
[image] 

That realy works great. Does anybody know whether its possible to filter the "localchanges" 

**image 2**
[image]

view so that those files are ignored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git and IntelliJ lines separator issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503036/git-and-intellij-lines-separator-issue)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bintellij-idea%5D+ignore+end-of-line+changes

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to ignore files that differ in line endings only.

Moreover, simply ignoring them does not look like a good idea - the files are modified and git working tree is dirty, which could prevent various git operations.

Looks like a better solution is to allow riveting all whitespace differences manually or on commit. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5227 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186765